# Class visible only to shared project?

Tags: c#

I want to separate platform-independent logic of my C# program into a shared project. Now I would like to hide repositories, service classes and such from my platform-specific projects. What access modifier can I use? `internal` doesn't seem to work, as they are compiled into the same executable (I think) and I don't want to go tag all my classes with `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`.

Is there a way to make classes in my shared project invisible to my platform-specific code?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one place where you need to know the *real* type you're trying to instance - the platform provider. Everyone else should just use the interfaces that are platform-invariant.

All the platform-specific implementations can then be private or internal for all you care - you just need to ensure the provider has access. Your application will use the platform-specific provider to get the platform-specific instances, while only ever using the platform-invariant interfaces.

As for "being compiled into a single executable", that's not really important. Most likely you care entirely about compile-time checking, and that's still present regardless of how the final executable is packaged. There's some restrictions on reflection in a partial trust environment, but by that point you shouldn't care - you're only in it for the compile checks, not the runtime safety.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature in C#. If you consider marking every other project with `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` an option, that would do the trick.

If possible, you could split off those other files (repositories, service files) to another assembly, which is not included in your shared project.